# System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip showing in WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to show a tooltip from Windows.Forms in wpf window. I need only this type of hint.

**1 option:**

```
ToolTip1.Show("Hello!", Application.Current.MainWindow, point, 5000);
```

intellisense error:

> Error CS1503 Argument 2: Can not convert from "System.Windows.Window"
>   to "System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window"

**2 option:**

```
System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window win32Window = new System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow();
((System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow)win32Window).AssignHandle(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle);
ToolTip1.Show("Hello!", win32Window, point, 5000);
```

runtime error:

> An exception is thrown: "System.ArgumentNullException" in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: The key can not be undefined.

Comment: First of all: why would you put a ToolTip on a Window? There are probably no applications that do it and it's for a reason...

Comment: ... and I wouldn't mix Windows.Forms with WPF.

Comment: I need exactly this, for this there are compelling reasons that I'm not going to explain to you. sorry if my english poor

Comment: http://www.ticklishtechs.net/2009/12/22/how-to-get-a-iwin32window-from-a-wpf-window/

Comment: Hans Passant, I saw this site and tried the method. In fact, this is the same thing and that is my second option. In the result, the same error is issued: "The key can not be undefined."

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know windows can not have tool tips.

To add tool tips for WPF controls you can use the built-in [ToolTipClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).

```
<Button Content="Submit">
  <Button.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Submit Request</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Submits the request to the server.</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ToolTip>
  </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

If you really need the tool tip for the window, one possible solution is to "simulate" the window:

- Make the window client area smaller and create a custom title bar and window border (make it so you can resize it, drag it, etc.)
- Add a invisible space to show the tool tip
- Set the tool tip for the "title bar"

Comment: Up-vote for a good answer, but I have to say, that "simulating" window that way can do the trick, but it is also extremly bad practice to do (I mean the idea of having to do it). If you need a ToolTip to explain users what your window is for, you should reconsider the purpose of your application...

Comment: I'm not a fool and I know about this method. In the question, I made it clear that I was interested in exactly what I was writing about, there are good reasons for this...